# Segmentation fault in recursive function when using smart pointers

Tags: c++, c++11, recursion, dynamic-programming, smart-pointers

I get a segmentation fault in the call to

```
auto n1=std::make_shared<Node>(n,n->x+i,n->y+j);
```

after a few recursive calls. Strange thing is that it's always at the same point in time. Can anyone spot the problem?
This is an implementation for a dynamic programming problem and here I'm accumulating the costs of a path. I have simplified the cost function but in this example the problem still occurs.

```
void HorizonLineDetector::dp(std::shared_ptr<Node> n)
{
    n->cost= 1 + n->prev->cost;
    //Check if we reached the last column(done!)
    if (n->x==current_edges.cols-1)
    {
        //Save the info in the last node if it's the cheapest path
        if (last_node->cost > n->cost)
        {
            last_node->cost=n->cost;
            last_node->prev=n;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        //Check for neighboring pixels to see if they are edges, launch dp with all the ones that are
        for (int i=0;i<2;i++)
        {
            for (int j=-1;j<2;j++)
            {
                if (i==0 && j==0) continue;
                if (n->x+i >= current_edges.cols || n->x+i < 0 ||
                    n->y+j >= current_edges.rows || n->y+j < 0) continue;
                if (current_edges.at<char>(n->y+j,n->x+i)!=0)
                {
                    auto n1=std::make_shared<Node>(n,n->x+i,n->y+j);
                    //n->next.push_back(n1);
                    nlist.push_back(n1);
                    dp(n1);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
class Node
{
    public:
        Node(){}
        Node(std::shared_ptr<Node> p,int x_,int y_){prev=p;x=x_;y=y_;lost=0;}
        Node(Node &n1){x=n1.x;y=n1.y;cost=n1.cost;lost=n1.lost;prev=n1.prev;}//next=n1.next;}
        std::shared_ptr<Node> prev;             //Previous and next nodes
        int cost;               //Total cost until now
        int lost;               //Number of steps taken without a clear path
        int x,y;
        Node& operator=(const Node &n1){x=n1.x;y=n1.y;cost=n1.cost;lost=n1.lost;prev=n1.prev;}//next=n1.next;}
        Node& operator=(Node &&n1){x=n1.x;y=n1.y;cost=n1.cost;lost=n1.lost;prev=n1.prev;n1.prev=nullptr;}//next=n1.next;n1.next.clear();}
};
```

[image: Error]

[image: Callstack]

Comment: Could you show the callstack on the sigsegv?

Comment: Which compiler (and version) are you using? Have you tried to create the shared pointer without make_shared?

Comment: Sure @xvan I just added the pic of the callstack.

Comment: @Schore I'm running Ubuntu 15.04 with gcc 4.9.2

Comment: The constructor looks ok to me, I'd bet on  `n->x` and `n->y` triggering the sigsegv. Test them outside `make_shared()`

Comment: Both n->x and n->y are accessed two lines above make_shared

Comment: Inside an `if`, though the call stack points that it's not the issue.

Comment: Have you checked how deep the recursion goes? Are you sure you're not overflowing the stack?

Comment: The problem is not x,y because even if I do something like auto n1=std::make_shared<Node>();
                    n1->x=x;
                    n1->y=y;
The error is in the make_shared line

Comment: @lonut that is my only guess but I don't think so, my memory barely increases. I'm trying to see how can I check if my stack is full, any suggestions?

Comment: I can see that I get to around 65400 recursive calls, it's too much but I'm not sure.

Comment: Yep, that's a long recursion. You can check the maximum stack size with `ulimit -s`. How much of it you're actually using is more tricky to find out, but you can get a fair idea if this might be the cause by looking at the maximum stack size and your recursion depth.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks like a pathological path search, in that it checks almost every path and doesn't keep track of paths it has already checked you can get to more than one way.

This will build recursive depth equal to the length of the longest path, and then the next longest path, and ... down to the shortest one.  Ie, something like O(# of pixels) depth.

This is bad.  And, as call stack depth is limited, will crash you.

The easy solution is to modify `dp` into `dp_internal`, and have `dp_internal` return a `vector` of nodes to process *next*.  Then write `dp`, which calls `dp_internal` and repeats on its return value.

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Node>>
HorizonLineDetector::dp_internal(std::shared_ptr<Node> n)
{
  std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Node>> retval;
```

...

```
            if (current_edges.at<char>(n->y+j,n->x+i)!=0)
            {
                auto n1=std::make_shared<Node>(n,n->x+i,n->y+j);
                //n->next.push_back(n1);
                nlist.push_back(n1);
                retval.push_back(n1);
            }
```

...

```
  return retval;
}
```

then `dp` becomes:

```
void HorizonLineDetector::dp(std::shared_ptr<Node> n)
{
  std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Node>> nodes={n};
  while (!nodes.empty()) {
    auto node = nodes.back();
    nodes.pop_back();
    auto new_nodes = dp_internal(node);
    nodes.insert(nodes.end(), new_nodes.begin(), new_nodes.end());
  }
}
```

but (A) this will probably just crash when the number of queued-up nodes gets ridiculously large, and (B) this just patches over the recursion-causes-crash, doesn't make your algorithm suck less.

---

Use A*.

This involves keeping track of which nodes you have visited and what nodes to process next with their current path cost.

You then use heuristics to figure out which of the ones to process next you should check first.  If you are on a grid of some sort, the heuristic is to use the shortest possible distance if nothing was in the way.

Add the cost to get to the node-to-process, plus the heuristic distance from that node to the destination.  Find the node-to-process that has the *least* total.  Process that one: you mark it as visited, and add all of its adjacent nodes to the list of nodes to process.

Never add a node to the list of nodes to process that you have already visited (as that is redundant work).

Once you have a solution, prune the list of nodes to process against any node whose current path value is greater than or equal to your solution.  If you *know* your heuristic is a strong one (that it is impossible to get to the destination faster), you can even prune based off of the total of heuristic and current cost.  Similarly, don't add to the list of nodes to process if it would be pruned by this paragraph.

The result is that your algorithm searches in a relatively strait line towards the target, and then expands outwards trying to find a way around any barriers. If there is a relatively direct route, it is used and the rest of the universe isn't even touched.

There are many optimizations on A* you can do, and even alternative solutions that don't rely on heuristics.  But start with A*.

Comment: Well thanks for the answer, I was expecting it but the fact is that I only posted a very reduced version of my code that reproduced the error. The questions was about programming, not algorithms so it's fine. In fact, in my program I do keep track of nodes visited at a lower cost and exit the dp function when I find this case. Also, the cost computation is not simply +1, it varies depending on several aspects of the image being checked.

Comment: @paghdv So, the `dp_internal` solution (where you queue up nodes to visit, instead of visiting them), then do the visiting outside in a loop, should solve the problem (blowing the stack).  It returning a `vector` then appending is one way, or it could take a container and insert items-to-visit into it.